# can't store latitude or longitude in string from location object

Tags: android, location

I'm making an application that requires location of the device. I have no issues with permissions and the location is being stored in the Location object. The latitudes and longitudes from the object are being displayed in text views too. However, when I write:

```
double d = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
```

the app crashes.

The code I have written is:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;

import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

public class NodeList extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final int REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE = 34;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private Location mLastLocation;
    private TextView lat;
    private TextView lon;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_node_list);
        mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");
        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, latitudes);
        mListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
        lat = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recLat);
        lon = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.recLon);
        getLastLocation();
        double d = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!checkPermissions()) {
            requestPermissions();
        }
    }



    private void startLocationPermissionRequest() {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(NodeList.this,
                new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION},
                REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    private void requestPermissions() {
        boolean shouldProvideRationale =
                ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
        if (shouldProvideRationale) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Displaying permission rationale to provide additional context.");

            showSnackbar(R.string.permission_rationale, android.R.string.ok,
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            // Request permission
                            startLocationPermissionRequest();
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "Requesting permission");
            startLocationPermissionRequest();
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
    private void getLastLocation() {
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                            mLastLocation = task.getResult();
                            lat.setText("Latitude: " + Double.toString(mLastLocation.getLatitude()));

                            lon.setText("Longitude: "+Double.toString(mLastLocation.getLongitude()));
                        } else {
                            Log.w(TAG, "getLastLocation:exception", task.getException());
                            showSnackbar(getString(R.string.no_location_detected));
                        }
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions,
                                           @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onRequestPermissionResult");
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                Log.i(TAG, "User interaction was cancelled.");
            } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                getLastLocation();
            } else {
                showSnackbar(R.string.permission_denied_explanation, R.string.settings,
                        new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                // Build intent that displays the App settings screen.
                                Intent intent = new Intent();
                                intent.setAction(
                                        Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
                                Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package",
                                        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID, null);
                                intent.setData(uri);
                                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        });
            }
        }
    }

}
```

This is really starting to frustrate me as I can't figure out what the mistake is.

The error in the log cat is :

```
10-11 12:58:51.817 9285-9285/com.mohana.pdc E/UncaughtException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mohana.pdc/com.mohana.pdc.NodeList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                                     at com.mohana.pdc.NodeList.onCreate(NodeList.java:83)
                                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
                                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757) 
10-11 12:58:52.048 9285-9285/com.mohana.pdc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                              Process: com.mohana.pdc, PID: 9285
                                                              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mohana.pdc/com.mohana.pdc.NodeList}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2659)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473)
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double android.location.Location.getLatitude()' on a null object reference
                                                                  at com.mohana.pdc.NodeList.onCreate(NodeList.java:83)
                                                                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6672)
                                                                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1140)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2612)
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2724) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1473) 
                                                                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123) 
                                                                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867) 
                                                                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Converting from double  to string String.valueof(mLastLocation.getLatitude())

Comment: I tried doing that, it's still crashing

Comment: post your crash log

Comment: Just posted the log cat

Comment: so, your lat and longitude values are null. check what's the problem getting lat and longitude

Answer (score 1):

Your method `getLastLocation()` updates your `mLastLocation` variable *asynchronously*. You can see that it's async by the fact that you had to use an `OnCompleteListener`.

What this means is that when you write:

```
getLastLocation();
double d = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
```

chances are **extremely** high that `mLastLocation` is still null at this point, and so your app will crash with a `NullPointerException`.

You'll have to move anything that depends on `mLastLocation` into the callback, or provide some other way of guaranteeing that the callback has executed before you try to use `mLastLocation`.

Comment: So will it work if I write the statement in onStart() or onResume()?

Comment: Not necessarily. It is _more likely_ to work, but it could easily still be `null` at that point.

Comment: A delay function for a period of 5 or 10 seconds would work right?

Comment: Same answer: not necessarily. You should stop trying to think about adding delays and instead just think about triggering whatever you want to do inside that `OnCompleteListener`.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert Double to String like this

```
String latitudeStr=String.valueOf(mLastLocation.getLatitude());
```